# processing-java fails on windows, works on Linux and Mac OSX, is there any way around this

Tags: processing

We have an automated grading script to compile Java, C++ and processing.
For C++ and Java, it works on all three platforms (Linux, Mac OSX, and Windows).  For processing, the command:

processing-java --sketch=a --output=test --build

works in both linux and Mac OSX. We are in a directory containing:

a/
   a.pde

the sketch a.pde is correctly inside a matching directory with the same name.

In Windows, processing-java reports "a\a.pde does not exist"

Comment: Can you post an example path you use on Windows ? (My rough uninformed guess is maybe the separator characters (```/``` on Linux and OSX but ```\``` on Windows) and/or spaces in the path might cause issues ?

Comment: literally sitting in the directory containing the directory a, we type:

processing-java --sketch=a --output=test --build

and it says "a\a.pde does not exist" but of course, it does.  The same thing works in Unix.

Comment: Where is a located ? straight at the root of the C drive ? (e.g. ```c:\a```) ?

Comment: You are right!  It requires an absolute path.  When we put in c:\path\a it works.  Put that as the answer and I will mark it.

Comment: done:) glad that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a case of processing-java not understanding relative paths.

Try to use absolute paths: e.g. `c:\a` instead of `a`.

```
processing-java --sketch=c:\a --output=test --build
```

In general, I recommend testing with absolute paths first and double checking separator characters (`/` on Linux,OSX, `\` on Windows)